# How to enable audio/video in Pidgin's XMPP for Google?

Tags: video, freebsd, pidgin

I have my regular "Google Talk" account configured in Pidgin and exchanging texts works fine.

Unfortunately, all of the options under the "Media" menu remain greyed out -- even though the computer has a webcam attached and other software can access it.

Does Pidgin support audio/video "out of the box", or do I need to switch to the alternative [purple-hangouts](https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts) add-on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing the media menu then your Pidgin is compiled with voice/video support.  If it's greyed out, then the other end of the connection isn't broadcasting that they support voice/video connections.

I have been working on adding voice/video support to the Hangouts plugin and for the most part it works, but I have seen that depending on what client the other person is using video doesn't always work

Comment: But of course the other side has voice/video -- I can (and do) ring them from my phone, using the Hangouts app...

Comment: Ah, but the other side is not using another XMPP client, which would broadcast that it supports XMPP Jingle for voice/video, rather than using Hangouts' WebRTC calling. Pidgin (or any other XMPP client) can only speak Jingle over XMPP

Comment: Could it be, their client would, actually, accept a voice/video connection the old way too -- even if it does not advertise it?